# How to Grant Write Access to Windows Server 2012 R2 Application Event Log

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, event-log

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and under that I'm running VMWare Workstation Pro.  When Workstation is installed, the user Group `__vmware__` is created for VMWare Workstation users.  I've added my host machine (i.e. Windows Server 2012 R2) user account (a member of Users, not a member of Administrators) to the `__vmware__` Group.

On the host I'd like to create event log entries in the Application event log while running as my user account related to the state of the virtual machines running under VMWare.

From a command window on the host, I type `whoami \all` and get the following:

```
USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name SID
========= ==============================================
mte\mike  S-1-5-21-1052476717-3500785571-2838594007-1118


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                 Type             SID
                           Attributes

========================================== ================ ====================
========================== =====================================================
==========
Everyone                                   Well-known group S-1-1-0
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

BUILTIN\Users                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

BUILTIN\Certificate Service DCOM Access    Alias            S-1-5-32-574
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

BUILTIN\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Alias            S-1-5-32-554
                           Group used for deny only

NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                   Well-known group S-1-5-4
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

CONSOLE LOGON                              Well-known group S-1-2-1
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users           Well-known group S-1-5-11
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

NT AUTHORITY\This Organization             Well-known group S-1-5-15
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

LOCAL                                      Well-known group S-1-2-0
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

Authentication authority asserted identity Well-known group S-1-18-1
                           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

MTE\__vmware__                             Alias            S-1-5-21-1052476717-
3500785571-2838594007-1131 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, L
ocal Group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level     Label            S-1-16-8192




PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                Description                    State
============================= ============================== ========
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking       Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set Disabled


USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.

Kerberos support for Dynamic Access Control on this device has been disabled.
```

Note that my user account is a member of `__vmware__` and the the SID is `S-1-5-21-1052476717-3500785571-2838594007-1131`.

From an Administrator account, I edit the following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application`

And modify the `CustomSD` entry as follows:

`O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-21-1052476717-3500785571-2838594007-1131)(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-2-1)(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)`

Here you can see that the `__vmware__` Group has been granted Read and Write access to the Application event log.

Yet, when I attempt to create a log entry:

`eventcreate /SO TestEventMsg /Id 1 /D "This is a test message" /T INFORMATION /L Application`

I get an Access denied error.

What am I not doing correctly?

UPDATE 2016-12-03

I tried the user2304170's suggestion and this is what I got:

```
PS C:\Users\Netadmin\Documents> ./GrantEventLogAccess.ps1 -Account '__vmware__' -LogName Application
Failed to save configuration or activate log Application. Access is denied.
name: Application
enabled: true
type: Admin
owningPublisher:
isolation: Application
channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-21-1052476717-3500785571-2838594007-1131)(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-2-1)(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)
(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)
logging:
  logFileName: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx
  retention: false
  autoBackup: false
  maxSize: 20971520
publishing:
  fileMax: 1
PS C:\Users\Netadmin\Documents>
```

Comment: Did you run user2304170's suggestion in an admin powershell window?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall and I've given up using Windows Server as a VM host.

Answer (score 0):

Puzzling stuff together on the internet I've created this little script for it:

```
<# 
    .SYNOPSIS   
        Add write permissions to the Windows Event Log for a specific AD object.

    .DESCRIPTION
        Add write permissions to the Windows Event Log for a specific AD object.

    .PARAMETER Account 
        Active directory object that needs write permissions.

    .PARAMETER LogName 
        Name of the log where we grant permissions

    .EXAMPLE
        ./script.ps! -Account 'Domain users' -LogName Application

    .NOTES
        CHANGELOG
        2016/09/12 Script born #>

Param (
    [String]$Account = 'Bob',
    [String]$LogName = 'Application'
)

Write-Verbose "Retrieving SID for account '$Account'"

$AdObj = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Account)
$SID = $AdObj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
Write-Verbose "Found SID for account $($SID.Value)" 

$w = wevtutil gl $LogName
$channelAccess = $w[5]

if ($channelAccess.Contains('channelAccess:')) {

    $str = $channelAccess.Replace('channelAccess: ','')

    if ($str.Contains($SID.Value) -eq $false) {
        $newstr = $str +"(A;;0x3;;;"+$SID.Value+")"
        Write-Verbose "Adding '$newstr'" 
        wevtutil sl $LogName /ca:$newstr
        Write-Verbose "Update complete new value is"
        wevtutil gl $LogName
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "Update not needed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try in a couple of weeks. Out of the country at the moment.

Comment: See my update.  I tried you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in full but if you go to this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog
```

You can right-click on the Eventlog folder and give permissions to the user you want to allow access or you can choose the Event log.

[image]

Comment: This did not work.